To which children should a Modifier parameter be applied?
We've hit a snag in our project discussion about whether the injected parameter modifier should affect just the top-level component or all components. Could you provide any input?
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
    navigateToGoalReading: () -> Unit,
    navigateToDetailEvent: () -> Unit,
) {
    val titleTextState by homeViewModel.titleTextState.collectAsState()
    val contentTextState by homeViewModel.contentTextState.collectAsState()
    val goalBookRead by homeViewModel.goalBookRead.collectAsState()
    val readingGoalGraphDataList by homeViewModel.goalReadingGraphDataList.collectAsState()
    val bookKingOfTheMonthDataList by homeViewModel.bookKingOfTheMonthDataList.collectAsState()

    MindWayAndroidTheme { colors, _ ->
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp, Alignment.Top),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = modifier
                .background(color = colors.WHITE)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
        ) {
            HomeNoticeCard(
                titleText = titleTextState,
                content = contentTextState,
                onClick = navigateToDetailEvent,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            )
            HomeGoalReadingChart(
                readNumberList = readingGoalGraphDataList,
                onClick = navigateToGoalReading,
                goalBookRead = goalBookRead,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(211.dp),
            )
            HomeReadersOfTheMonthChart(
                bookKingOfTheMonthData = bookKingOfTheMonthDataList,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(239.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            )
        }
    }
}

VS
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
    navigateToGoalReading: () -> Unit,
    navigateToDetailEvent: () -> Unit,
) {
    val titleTextState by homeViewModel.titleTextState.collectAsState()
    val contentTextState by homeViewModel.contentTextState.collectAsState()
    val goalBookRead by homeViewModel.goalBookRead.collectAsState()
    val readingGoalGraphDataList by homeViewModel.goalReadingGraphDataList.collectAsState()
    val bookKingOfTheMonthDataList by homeViewModel.bookKingOfTheMonthDataList.collectAsState()

    MindWayAndroidTheme { colors, _ ->
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp, Alignment.Top),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = modifier
                .background(color = colors.WHITE)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
        ) {
            HomeNoticeCard(
                titleText = titleTextState,
                content = contentTextState,
                onClick = navigateToDetailEvent,
                modifier = modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            )
            HomeGoalReadingChart(
                readNumberList = readingGoalGraphDataList,
                onClick = navigateToGoalReading,
                goalBookRead = goalBookRead,
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(211.dp),
            )
            HomeReadersOfTheMonthChart(
                bookKingOfTheMonthData = bookKingOfTheMonthDataList,
                modifier = modifier
                    .height(239.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            )
        }
    }
}

I have looked into Now in Android and Chris Banes' article Always provide a Modifier parameter, as well as Google Open Source's API Guidelines for Jetpack Compose, but I couldn't find a convincing answer. I would greatly appreciate a definitive answer.

by using an top level modifier which could be used somewhere too , it's properties will be used in the composable you put and it does not affect the top level composable's.

Could you let me know which of the above codes is correct? The difference lies in Modifier modifier.

You can use modifier , you can mention common designs at top level like width you mentioned and the height for individual components.

Please have a look at the documentation about Modifier:

It's a best practice to have all of your composables accept a modifier parameter, and pass that modifier to its first child that emits UI.

So according to the convention, you should apply the Modifier that is passed into the Composable to the topmost nested Composable, which in your case is the Column.
However, there might be situations where it is perfectly reasonable to pass in a Modifier that is applied to some nested children. I then would suggest to name the parameter differently (not "modifier"), for example
@Composable
MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier,        // Modifier applied to first nested Composable
    childModifier: Modifier    // Modifier applied to some deeply nested Composable
) {
    
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = childModifier,
            text = "Hello World"
        )
    }

}


I sincerely appreciate your response. Thank you.
